# What is the advantage of JCXZ?

Tags: dos, x86-16, assembly

I have the following code,

### Objective:

Display a row of N `*` symbols

### Code:

```
MOV CX, N
MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, '*'
JCXZ END_P
BACK:
    INT 21H
    LOOP BACK
END_P:
```

The above example was shown to tell how to use `JCXZ` but I don't get it. Even if I remove `JCXZ`, it would do the same work. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think it would do the same thing without `jcxz`?  What would happen with and without the `jcxz` if n is zero?

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought for a moment that it could be a do while loop but said no to myself. Thanks for clearing it out.

Answer (score 3):

It most certainly will not do the same thing if CX = 0!  The INT 21H call is skipped if CX=0, but done otherwise.